# How to get map to parse input bounds as degrees?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I just started to learn Open Map and I am having some difficulty working with the API. This may look trivial, but please bear with me. I am trying to get Open Map to display a region of the map bounded by the `bounds` variable. Having specified the unit as `degrees`, I would expect that the bounds shown would also be in degrees. But it seems to me that it is in a different unit which is much smaller than degrees:

```
var options = {
 projection: 'EPSG:4326'
 ,units: 'degrees'
};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-100, -90, 100, 90);
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();            
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets");
map.addLayers([osm, gmap]);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.zoomToExtent(bounds, true);
```

My question is, how do I get open map to parse the input bounds as degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use transform method of OpenLayers.Bounds object:

```
epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
bbox = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-100, -80, 100, 80);
bounds = bbox.transform(epsg4326,epsg900913);
```